# How to filter Ansible JSON result or output?

Tags: json, ansible

Doing the Linux Patching through Ansible Automation. Once the patching is completed from the JSON output I need to get some details.

Find the below code when I execute the playbook it does not give proper output from the JSON.

**Playbook 1**

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    contents: "{{ lookup('file', '/ansible/linuxpatch.json') | from_json }}"
  tasks:
    - name: calling file
      debug:
        msg={{ contents.msg | list }}
      register: msg

    - name: update
      set_fact:
        result: "{{ msg | json_query('*.Installed') }}"
```

**Playbook 2**

```yaml
    - name: report update count
      set_fact:
        update_info: "{{ msg | to_json | from_json | json_query(update_info_query) }}"
      vars:
        update_info_query: >
          *[].{
            Installed: Installed,
          }
```

From the JSON output I need only the `Installed` details.

**JSON Output**

```json
{
    "msg": [
        "",
        true,
        [
            "Installed: NetworkManager-tui-1:1.44.0-4.el9_3.x86_64",
            "Installed: NetworkManager-team-1:1.44.0-4.el9_3.x86_64",
            "Installed: NetworkManager-libnm-1:1.44.0-4.el9_3.x86_64",
            "Installed: NetworkManager-1:1.44.0-4.el9_3.x86_64",
            "Installed: libxml2-2.9.13-5.el9_3.x86_64",
            "Installed: policycoreutils-3.5-3.el9_3.x86_64",
            "Installed: kernel-tools-libs-5.14.0-362.18.1.el9_3.x86_64",
            "Installed: kernel-tools-5.14.0-362.18.1.el9_3.x86_64",
            "Installed: kernel-modules-5.14.0-362.18.1.el9_3.x86_64",
            "Installed: kernel-core-5.14.0-362.18.1.el9_3.x86_64",
            "Installed: kernel-5.14.0-362.18.1.el9_3.x86_64",
            "Installed: grub2-tools-minimal-1:2.06-70.el9_3.2.rocky.0.2.x86_64",
            "Installed: grub2-tools-extra-1:2.06-70.el9_3.2.rocky.0.2.x86_64",
            "Installed: grub2-tools-efi-1:2.06-70.el9_3.2.rocky.0.2.x86_64",
            "Installed: grub2-tools-1:2.06-70.el9_3.2.rocky.0.2.x86_64",
            "Installed: kernel-modules-core-5.14.0-362.18.1.el9_3.x86_64",
            "Installed: grub2-efi-x64-1:2.06-70.el9_3.2.rocky.0.2.x86_64",
            "Installed: openssl-libs-1:3.0.7-25.el9_3.x86_64",
            "Installed: openssl-1:3.0.7-25.el9_3.x86_64",
            "Installed: rocky-repos-9.3-1.2.el9.noarch",
            "Installed: rocky-release-9.3-1.2.el9.noarch",
            "Installed: rocky-gpg-keys-9.3-1.2.el9.noarch",
            "Installed: python-unversioned-command-3.9.18-1.el9_3.1.noarch",
            "Installed: python3-libs-3.9.18-1.el9_3.1.x86_64",
            "Installed: python3-3.9.18-1.el9_3.1.x86_64",
            "Installed: gnutls-3.7.6-23.el9_3.3.x86_64",
            "Installed: grub2-common-1:2.06-70.el9_3.2.rocky.0.2.noarch",
            "Installed: selinux-policy-targeted-38.1.23-1.el9_3.1.noarch",
            "Installed: sqlite-libs-3.34.1-7.el9_3.x86_64",
            "Installed: systemd-udev-252-18.el9.0.1.rocky.x86_64",
            "Installed: systemd-rpm-macros-252-18.el9.0.1.rocky.noarch",
            "Installed: selinux-policy-38.1.23-1.el9_3.1.noarch",
            "Installed: systemd-pam-252-18.el9.0.1.rocky.x86_64",
            "Installed: systemd-libs-252-18.el9.0.1.rocky.x86_64",
            "Installed: systemd-252-18.el9.0.1.rocky.x86_64",
            "Installed: tzdata-2024a-1.el9.noarch",
            "Installed: nss-util-3.90.0-4.el9_3.x86_64",
            "Installed: nss-softokn-freebl-3.90.0-4.el9_3.x86_64",
            "Installed: nss-softokn-3.90.0-4.el9_3.x86_64",
            "Installed: python3-firewall-1.2.5-2.el9_3.noarch",
            "Installed: firewalld-filesystem-1.2.5-2.el9_3.noarch",
            "Installed: firewalld-1.2.5-2.el9_3.noarch",
            "Installed: nspr-4.35.0-4.el9_3.x86_64",
            "Removed: NetworkManager-1:1.44.0-3.el9.x86_64",
            "Removed: NetworkManager-libnm-1:1.44.0-3.el9.x86_64",
            "Removed: NetworkManager-team-1:1.44.0-3.el9.x86_64",
```

---

It's works in the JSON output file but how to add into the actual playbook.

When i tried to add into the play book it's give error.

---

- hosts: prod
  become: yes
  #become_user: root
  tasks:

  - name: Cleaning yum log file
    shell: yum clean all
  - name: INstalling the patching
    yum:
    name: '*'
    state: latest
    register: list
  - debug:
    msg: "{{ list.values() | list }}"
    register: msg
  - reboot:
    reboot_timeout: 3600
  - name: Final Output
    set_fact:
    update_info: "{{ msg | map('msg') | json_query('[].Installed') }}"
  - debug:
    var: installed

Comment: Can you provide the content of `linuxpatch.json`? And maybe where it comes from or how it is generated?

Comment: the linuxpatch.json is a file which i have copied the JSON output content while doing the patch on Linux machine.

Answer (score 1):

The expression below does what you want

```yaml
    installed: "{{ contents.msg.2 | map('from_yaml') |
                                    json_query('[].Installed') }}"
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    contents: "{{ lookup('file', 'linuxpatch.json') | from_yaml }}"
    installed: "{{ contents.msg.2 | map('from_yaml') |
                                    json_query('[].Installed') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: installed
```

Comment: it's works in the JSON output file but how to add into the actual playbook.

When i tried to add into the play book it's give error.

Comment: Try the playbook in my example. There are no errors.

Comment: There are no errors. But same thing i need to implement in the actual playbook, once the patch has been installed the list of Installed packages need to be export into an output